# Prove that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a disjoint union of open intervals

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of an at most countable collection if disjoint segments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181641/every-open-set-in-mathbbr-is-the-union-of-an-at-most-countable-collection-i)

Here, we're using the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}$, and the endpoints are allowed to be positive and negative infinity.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181641/every-open-set-in-mathbbr-is-the-union-of-an-at-most-countable-collection-i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sketch proof:** Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open. About every point $u \in U$ there is an open interval containing $u$ which lies wholly in $U$, and each such open interval contains a rational number. So we can write $U$ as a countable union of open intervals about rationals. Enumerate these rationals as $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. You can get a collection of disjoint open intervals whose union is $U$ by taking each $q_n$ in turn $-$ if $q_n$ lies in a set already picked then throw it away; otherwise, choose $0 < a,b \le \infty$ maximal such that $(q_n-a, q_n+b) \subseteq U$. These chosen intervals are pairwise disjoint and their union is $U$.

I leave the details to you.

Comment: The selection of a subset of Q cannot be finished in a finite number of steps, so this proof may not be correct?

Answer (score 5):

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$  be open. Define a relation in $U$ by $x \sim y$ if there is an open interval $I \subseteq U$ such that $x,y \in I$. Prove that this is an equivalence relation and that its classes are open intervals.

Comment: 3. prove that this gives you a countable set of classes

Comment: @Auke, sure, but that was not part of the original question.

Comment: you are right, I was confused by Clive's answer :)