# Step function existence for a simple function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\varphi : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a simple function and let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Prove that there is a step function $g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x) = \varphi(x)$ except on a set of measure $\varepsilon$.

I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Comment: A Lebesgue measurable set can be approximated by an open set. An open set can be approximated by a finite union of open intervals (an open set is a countable union of intervals).

Comment: @DavidMitra: your last point, the approximation: what does it follow from?

Comment: @Alex An open set $O$ of $\Bbb R$ can be written as a countable union of disjoint open intervals (see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197954/prove-that-every-open-set-in-mathbbr-is-a-disjoint-union-of-open-intervals)). If $O$ has finite measure, then finitely many of these will give most of the mass of $O$.