# Can anybody give me a pictorial representation

Tags: calculus

It is said that an open interval is a countable union of disjoint intervals.

I do not get a vision of how this is possible.

For example if we consider$(0,3)$.if we write 
$(0,1)U(1,2)U(2,3)$ then it will exclude the point  $1$ and $2$.I mean this will happen always..

Can anybody represent $(0,4)$ as a union of disjoint open intervals

Comment: Since $\emptyset$ is disjoint to every other set and an interval, you can take the union to be the interval itself and a bunch of empty sets.

Comment: Many proofs have been given for this (e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-at-most-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-interv)). Though I think [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197954/prove-that-every-open-set-in-mathbbr-is-a-disjoint-union-of-open-intervals) is the most helpful visually.

Comment: Then that is true for every set.What is the scope of saying this sir.

Comment: Perhaps you read that an open _set_, rather than an open _interval_, is a countable union of disjoint intervals. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you want to say that an open interval is a countable union of disjoint ***closed*** intervals?

Comment: Well if the intervals can be clopen... Example (0,2) = union (1/(n+1),1/n] U (1,2).

Comment: Also finite is countable, isn't it? Discounting the empty set (and dirty trick) I'm fairly certain an open interval is not the union of more than one disjoint open interval.  Where have you heard it said? I've never heard it.  I think you are mishearing every open *set* **in R** is an *at most* countable union of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: I read it from the book (Real Analysis) of renowned Professor Ranbir sing Dhoot page 394

He says 
if says if $G$ is an open set of $[a,b]$ then G can be written as countable union of mutually disjoint open intervals ${I_n}$ 
that is $$G=UI_n$$ where $I_n\intersection I_m=\phi$