# Set theory - Solution without using the Axiom of Choice.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, axiom-of-choice

I have a question and I want to know if my solution is correct. If it's not, I would like to know why. Anyway, I would love to see more solutions to this problem. There is the problem: 
Let $A \subseteq P(\mathbb{R})$ Be a set of open Intervals, when there are no empty sets involved ($\emptyset \notin A$). 
. if $C_1,C_2 \in A$,      $C_1 \neq C_2 \rightarrow C_1 \cap C_2=\emptyset$. We need to prove that $|A|\leq \aleph_0$. 
At the first time I solved it using the Axiom of Choice, using the fact that we can find a rational number in any non-empty open interval (It helps because $|\mathbb{Q}|=\aleph_0$). 
 Now I am required to solve it without using the axiom of choice. There is my solution, Is it correct? 
For any real number $r$, let $r_n$ be the smallest integer that is bigger then r. For each $(a,b) \in A$, define $d_{(a,b)}$ as $d_{(a,b)}=|b-a|$. 
 Also, let $n_{(a,b)}$ be the smallest natural number $n$ such that $\frac{1}{10^n}<d_{(a,b)}$. 
let $k_{(a,b)}$ be the biggest $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b_n-x \cdot \frac{1}{10^{n_{(a,b)}}} \geq b$. 

Now define a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ the following way: 
$$
f((a,b))=
\begin{cases}
\frac{a+b}{2},& \text{if } a \in \mathbb{Q},b \in \mathbb{Q} \\
a+\frac{1}{10^{n_{(a,b)}}}, & \text{if } a \in \mathbb{Q},b \notin \mathbb{Q}\\
b-\frac{1}{10^{n_{(a,b)}}}, & \text{if } a \notin \mathbb{Q},b \in \mathbb{Q}\\
b_n-(k_{(a,b)}+1)\cdot \frac{1}{10^{n_{(a,b)}}} & \text{if } a \notin \mathbb{Q},b \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, this is not that hard to show that $f((a,b))$ is a rational number $q \in (a,b)$. also, we never get the same rational number twice because $C_1 \neq C_2 \rightarrow C_1 \cap C_2=\emptyset$. So this is Injective function which is exactly what we wanted. Is this solution correct? I am not using the axiom of choice, right? Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98923/open-sets-of-mathbbr1-and-axiom-of-choice/

Comment: That reminds me of the first time I proved this sort of proposition in front of a classroom full of first-semester freshmen. I later honed and refined this to avoid the very explicit and overly complicated algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is perfectly correct.  Note that you can avoid all your complicated casework by fixing once and for all a bijection $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ and then define $f((a,b))=g(n)$ for the least $n$ such that $g(n)\in (a,b)$.  (Of course, defining such a bijection $g$ explicitly would involve some sort of casework similar to what you did, but fixing such a bijection ahead of time makes the argument conceptually a lot simpler.)